Wike does not work in Ubuntu 24.04
I install wike with APT. It does not run. When I run it from terminal, I get the following error.
$ wike

(process:11686): Gtk-WARNING **: 02:55:41.246: Unknown key gtk-modules in /home/archisman/.config/gtk-4.0/settings.ini
bwrap: setting up uid map: Permission denied

** (wike:11686): ERROR **: 02:55:41.837: Failed to fully launch dbus-proxy: Child process exited with code 1
Trace/breakpoint trap

How to fix it?

This is due to recent changes in apparmor.
As a workaround, create the file /etc/apparmor.d/wike (you will need sudo previledges) with the following content
# This profile allows everything and only exists to give the
# application a name instead of having the label "unconfined"

abi <abi/4.0>,
include <tunables/global>

profile wike /usr/bin/wike flags=(unconfined) {
  userns,

  # Site-specific additions and overrides. See local/README for details.
  include if exists <local/wike>
}

Then run sudo systemctl restart apparmor.service
